# coqtop -lv (version 8.6) no longer displaying proof subgoals?

Tags: coq

The command `coqtop -lv` under version 8.4 displays the proof subgoal, while it seemingly no longer does so under version 8.6. For example, if we look at:

```
(* file le.v *)

 Theorem lt_le: forall n p: nat, n < p -> n <= p.
 Proof.
```

With version 8.4 the command `coqtop -lv le.v` gives the output:

```
Welcome to Coq 8.4pl4 (July 2014)
Theorem lt_le: forall n p: nat, n < p -> n <= p.
1 subgoal

  ============================
   forall n p : nat, n < p -> n <= p
Proof.
1 subgoal

  ============================
   forall n p : nat, n < p -> n <= p

lt_le <
```

However, using version 8.6 I obtain:

```
Welcome to Coq 8.6 (December 2016)
Theorem lt_le: forall n p: nat, n < p -> n <= p.
Proof.

lt_le <
```

Obviously when designing proofs the 8.4 behavior is desirable. How do I achieve the same under 8.6?

**EDIT**: As pointed out by @nobody I can use the `Show` command either interactively or within the source file. So the question really becomes whether version 8.6 has an option setting somewhere which makes the verbose mode call `Show` by default without having to explicitly call it everywhere within the source file, which seems to be the behavior of version 8.4.

Comment: I played around with this for a while and couldn't find a setting for this. A workaround is to explicitly type `Show.`, which will print the current proof state. Subsequent tactic uses will trigger automatic printing, so it's just the first step after loading the file where this is annoying.

Comment: Thanks v much nobody. I was unaware of `Show` so this is very useful. Surely there must be an option setting somewhere allowing us to make it implicit.

Comment: From what I tested, this is a regression that was introduced in version 8.5. It probably went unnoticed because not many people actually use `coqtop` directly to write proofs. Any reason for not using Proof General, or CoqIDE, or [CoqPIDE](https://coqpide.bitbucket.io/?) or the more recent [vscode mode](https://github.com/siegebell/vscoq)?

Comment: @Zimmi48 yes I work under Linux and like working with all my files directly from `vim` (with the command `:!coqtop -lv filename`) or handle my files with various shell scripts, just like I would with assembly, C, C++, Java, Haskell, Scheme, Python etc. My IDE is my OS+`vim`+`bash`. `emacs` would be a solution but I have no yet invested in learning it. Thanks v much for your help!.

Comment: I just reported your problem as a comment on the commit that changed the behavior of coqtop: https://github.com/coq/coq/commit/3f64bf1be849d1c4040b4d06a3417abd1a57f7d2

Comment: @Zimmi48 thanks very much for that!